# Slingshot doesn't find sub items

Tags: slingshot

Coming from Gnome3, I'm used to being able to open the keyboard settings tool (gnome-control-center keyboard) by pressing the "Super" (on PC: the Windows key) key and typing "keyboard". The keyboard settings tool resides in the "Settings" group and can thus be regarded as a sub item to "Settings", but I discovered that Slingshot only finds top-level items such as "Settings" but not the sub items (eg. keyboard settings).

The semantics of this behavior can be seen as "I (slingshot) doesn't know anything about keyboards" or "This OS does not have a tool for managing the keyboard", which of course is false :)

(As a side note - it is consistent with the behavior in OSX, but that doesn't mean that it's "done right" - I was just as stumbled to find out that I can't search for the keyboard settings in OSX either)

Is this a bug, or is it intentional?

Answer (score 1):

Slingshot accually does show subitems. If you search for "Keyboard" it will show it on the bottom:
[image]

Same goes for all the other plugs of Slingshot.

Thing to note: this feature only has been added a while ago, you might want to update your system.